# Connect BigQuery with Power BI- Best Practice and Cost Effective way

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, powerbi, business-intelligence

Cost Effective way to connect Google BigQuery with Power BI. What intermediate layer is required in between GCP and Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

You can access `BigQuery` directly from `DataStudio` using a custom query or loading the whole table. Technically nothing is necessary between **BigQuery** and **DataStudio**.

Regarding best practices, if your dashboard reads a lot of data and its constantly used it can lead to a high cost. In this case a "layer" makes sense.
If this is your case you could pre-aggregate your data in BigQuery to avoid a big amount of data to be read many times by DataStudio. My suggestion is:

1. Create a process (could be a scheduled query) that periodically aggregate your data and then save it in another table
2. In DataStudio read your data from the aggregated table

These steps can help you reducing costs and also can make your dashboards loading faster. The negative point is that if you are working with streaming data this approach in general will not let you see the most recent registries unless you run the aggregation process very constantly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my requirement is to read BigQuery from Power BI.

Comment: @GaneshSundar my bad. In your case you can use this connector (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-bigquery). Nevertheless, consider pre-aggregating your data